Proving $\sum_{i=0}^{k}\left((i^{2} - i +(k-1)(kx^{2}-2ix)) (1-x)^{\left(k-i\right)}(x^{i}) {k \choose i} \right) = 0$
I need help proving the following finite sum is equal to $0$:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k}\big(i^{2} - i +(k-1)(kx^{2}-2ix)\big) (1-x)^{k-i}x^{i} {k \choose i}.
$$
I am unsure if this is a telescoping series or if there's a particular symmetry that I can exploit to show this is $0$. This came up in a context where I am trying to show a log-likelihood function is concave.

Welcome to MSE! I haven’t seen the accepted answer, but I see $(1-x)^{k-i}x^i \binom{k}{i}$, so using normal distribution and telescopic series can be a way.


$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^k \left(i^2-i+(k-1)(kx^2-2ix)\right)(1-x)^{k-i}x^i\binom k i = 0$.

Enough to show that:
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{k} \left( i^2(1-x)^{k-i}x^i\binom k i \right)  - ((2k-2)x+1)\sum_{i=0}^{k} \left(i(1-x)^{k-i}x^{i}\binom k i \right) \\ \displaystyle + k(k-1)x^2\sum_{i=0}^{k} \left( (1-x)^{k-i}x^i \binom k i \right) =0.$
Using normal/binomial distribution(if you're suspicious, please do it yourself or put it into Wolfram Alpha or else), we get:
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{k} \left(i^2 (1-x)^{k-i}x^i\binom k i \right) = E(x^2) = E(x)^2+V(x) = k^2x^2+kx(1-x)$
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{k} \left(i (1-x)^{k-i}x^i\binom k i \right) = E(x)=kx$
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{k} \left( (1-x)^{k-i}x^i\binom k i \right) = 1$
Putting each term into the equation, we're done.
